# Deleting files with almost identical file names in CMD

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a folder with multiple photos in it with two different resolutions for each photo. I want to delete the photos with lower resolution. For example the folder contains the following files WP_20140917_19_15_04_Pro.jpg and WP_20140917_19_15_04_Pro__highres.jpg. I want to keep all the photos with the highres in the filename and delete the other one with use of CMD.

One important note is that it should only delete the photo if a highres version of the photo exists, because the folder does not always contains highres versions of the photos.

I know how to delete files when a certain word is repeatedly returned (such as highres), but I can't do the opposite, that is why I don't know how to start. All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
set /a count=0
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*__highres.*" '
 ) DO (
 SET "name=%%a"
 SET "name=!name:__highres=!"
 IF EXIST "%sourcedir%\!name!" (
  ECHO(DEL "%sourcedir%\!name!"
  set /a count+=1
 )
)
echo %count% files deleted.

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The required DEL commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(DEL` to `DEL` to actually delete the files.

Uber-simple. Read the directory, targeting all files matching the pattern `*__highres.*`. Remove the `__highres` from the name and if a file exists with the modified name, delete it.

---edit : added-in count of deleted files.

Comment: Thank you. To make sure I did not change the echo(del to del. I have counted the number of highres photos. That should also mean that the number of deleted files should be equal. What should I include in the batch file to show me the number of 'deleted' files ?